# What does D3's "empty" selection do?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new at D3 and recently saw this piece of code while someone was creating a transition: `d3.select({})` in `d3.select({}).transition()` etc. This seems to be doing the same thing as `d3.select([])`. In the console, it showed up as an array, but I'm still unsure what it does. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That looks quite interesting! Where have you seen it? Could you share a link? It's hard to tell what's it good for without having any context.

Comment: I found it here (line 49): http://codepen.io/atticweb/pen/GZKvgv while trying to make a real-time graph from here: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642874. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only place I've seen this is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9539958).  Now usually you would `d3.select` the object you want to run the transition on.  But in the linked example, Bostock is **not** operating on svg composed of different DOM objects to manipulate but instead on a canvas that has to be wiped and redrawn for each step in the transition.  So, `d3.select({}).transition()`, simply becomes an easy way to fire up a generic transition he can work with.  You should note that something has to be selected to create a transition, just doing `d3.select().transition()` won't work and an empty object (or an empty array) allows it to work.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems like just a quick way to get a transition going then. Got it.

Comment: It's worth noting, that this will create a **new** transition every time it is called. My first thought was to use [`d3.transition()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_transition) to create a transition. In this case it won't work as one might think, though, because it is equivalent to `d3.select(document).transition()` whereby interrupting the transition previously started on `document`. When selecting an empty object to start off a transition, all these transitions are independent of each other and may thus run simultaneously. @PeterQiu

Comment: Here's an example of this trick used on SVG: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ (line 143 in the index js file in sources)